# Animated template hosting dynamic content

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, flexbox, transition

I want to create a template that can be reused. The template will look something like this (although I'm actually using react components, I've boiled it down to a straight up css problem here):

```js
var content = [
                "<div class='banner-content-big'></div>",
                "<div class='banner-content-small'></div>"
              ];
              
var contentIndex = 0;

function toggleBanner() {
  contentIndex = ++contentIndex > 1 ? 0 : contentIndex;
  
  var banner = document.getElementsByClassName("template-banner")[0];
  
  banner.innerHTML = content[contentIndex];
}
```

```css
.template-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
  
.template-banner {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0;
}

.template-main {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1 0;
 }

.banner-content-small {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
}

.banner-content-big {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
 
.main-content {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="template-container" onclick="toggleBanner()">
  <div class="template-banner">
    <div class="banner-content-big"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="template-main">
    <div class="main-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- template-banner grow/shrinks to fit its content perfectly
- but I can't figure out **how to add a transition that will nicely animate the change in template-banner height**.
- important constraint is that the *transition needs to be defined in the template component*, not in the components (divs here) that are being inserted into the template-banner.

It feels like this should be a transition on the flexbox, but I can't find a way to make that happen.

Comment: did you try to add transition and see what happen ?

Comment: Why don't you just increase and decrease the height, instead of adding/removing elements ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif : Yes - many variations

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa : This is a highly simplified version of a react implementation.  The whole point is to contain reusable logic into a template component that can be re-used many times.  By having the template component define the transition, it will be standardized across the application.  If I change the properties of the transition, it will change everywhere across the application.

Comment: It is seeming that this might not be possible. https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/